# Best field type for cryptocurrency big numbers?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, datatypes

I'm using PostgreSQL for my cryptocurrency exchange database, the question is: for saving currency amount (numbers) with their precision (like 323232323232323.45454545 ~ 23 digit + 1 dot: 15 digit before dot and 8 digit after that), Should I use `varchar(24)` type for them or `double precision` or `numeric(15,8)` ?

**Edit:** `numeric(23,8)` is right for having 15 digit before dot and 8 digit after that!

**Note:** It seems that `double precision` type cant properly save big numbers like example above and it will be rounded to 323232323232323!

Witch one has better performance (speed) and needs less resources?

Comment: Never use floating point type for currency. And why on earth would you choose to store numbers as `varchar(24)`?

Comment: @mustaccio I just asked for `string` type for performance because `numeric(15,8)` taking too many bits I think. and what's `floating point type` btw, it is like **1.245e18**?

Comment: `numeric` is the right choice. A `text` or `varchar` column will be **way** less efficient than `numeric` (and they will use much more storage space as well)

Comment: That's NUMERIC(23,8) by the way

Comment: OK, thanks. I edited my question.

Comment: Which did you end up using?